# ~/.xinitrc not being run

Tags: ubuntu, x11, lightdm

I am not able to run my `~/.xinitrc` (`~/.xsession`) scripts when logging into my computer.  I'm using Xubuntu 12.10 with vanilla lightgm as the login manager.  Both these files have the right permission (executable).  I have in my `~/.xinitrc`, the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

# read ~/.Xmodmap if it exists
if [[ -f "${HOME}/.Xmodmap" ]]; then
    xmodmap "${HOME}/.Xmodmap"
fi

# read ~/.Xresources if it exists
if [[ -f "${HOME}/.Xresources" ]]; then
    xrdb -load "${HOME}/.Xresources"
fi

# use gnome-keyring-daemon to manage keys
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh
```

Any other command (like `date >> "$HOME/did_start"`) is not also being executed.

Now apparently, even if I delete my `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xsession` files, `xmodmap` seems to be reading `~/.Xmodmap`, and `~/.Xresources` is also being partly read.  I checked in `/etc/X11/Xsession` to see if there are any commands which makes it read these two files, and found none. What could be happening?

**EDIT:** Since Gilles asked, I'm using a custom session while login in through lightdm (`/usr/share/xsessions/custom.desktop`):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xsession
Exec=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

But apparently this still starts XFCE via `startxfce4` even though I don't have it in my `~/.xinitrc`.

And as Ulrich Dangel pointed out, there is a line in `/usr/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` which reads `~/.Xmodmap` and `~/.Xresources`, and this script is executed by `startxfce4`.  So that "mystery" is now resolved.  But again, the colors (for `xterm`, `urxvt` etc.) from `~/.xinitrc` is still not being loaded.

Comment: How’s going your process of logging in? What sessions are available (if any)?

Comment: What session type do you choose in lightdm?

Comment: @Gilles I am using a custom session.  I've updated my question with more information on that.

Answer (score 6):

For your first question, it typically depends on your session, i.e. the file in your example is not necessarily sufficient as it doesn't start your WM/DE. Normally `~/.xsession` or `~/.xinitrc` start the whole environment and are not only used to automatically launch some programs, i.e. they should contain a line like `exec x-window-manager` but the global `xsession` may just source the file.

For your other question, Debian (and probably Ubuntu) have `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` which for example loads `~/.Xresources`. These files are also responsible for loading and finding the default window manager.

To debug your issues you should have a look in `~/.xsession-errors` or start the xserver from a console and see the error messages directly there, i.e. `startx -- /etc/X11/Xsession`

Comment: For the first part, even though I don't have a `exec startxfce4` line in my `~/.xinitrc`, XFCE starts (it's weird, something else must be happening).  For the second part, yes, what you said seems to be the case. The `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc` script caused the two files to be read.

Comment: @metwarp ok updated the comment